# Update Cell based on POST parameter App Script

Tags: post, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

Im making a POST request to URL

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/{id}/exec?row=5
```

The request is `application/json` and the request body is `{"json": true}`

this is received by an app script which is published as web app (anyone, anonymous)

```
function doPost(e){

   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("16XSfRDLY1RdrUxHujbRCPX6eSh4CqP7ES2kVVDCGgoI");
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("INGRESOSDEDINERO");
 
var params=JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
   params=JSON.parse(params);

   var myObj=JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

   var row=myObj.row;


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActivesheet();

  ss.getRange(row,4).setValue("CONTACTED");
 
  
  console.log("Post function called");
if (typeof e !== 'undefined')
console.log(e.parameter);
sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue(JSON.stringify(e));

}
```

I'm trying to pass a row number i want to modify as a paramenter. I want to update the cell corresponding to row number, column 5 with a fixed value "CONTACTED". Its not working and under Stackdriver logging i cant see the log despite using `console.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to give the value of `row` using the query parameter like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{id}/exec?row=5`.
- From your script,

  - You want to put the value of `JSON.stringify(e)` to the range of `getRange(row,4)` in the sheet `INGRESOSDEDINERO` of Spreadsheet `16XSfRDLY1RdrUxHu...`.
  - You want to put the value of `CONTACTED` to the range of `getRange(row,4)` in the 1st tab of the active Spreadsheet.

In order to achieve your goal by modifying your script, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modification points:

- I think that you are trying to retrieve the values requested as the query parameter with the request body. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- When `row` is given by the query parameter like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{id}/exec?row=5`, you can retrieve `row` from `e` of `doPost(e)` with `e.parameter.row`.
- For example, when you request the Web Apps using a script, when a value is returned like `return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok")`, no error occurs.
- If you want to use `getActiveSheet()`, please modify `getActivesheet` to `getActiveSheet()`.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `row` is used as the query parameter like your endpoint.

#### Modified script:

```
function doPost(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("16XSfRDLY1RdrUxHujbRCPX6eSh4CqP7ES2kVVDCGgoI");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("INGRESOSDEDINERO");
  var row = e.parameter.row;  // <--- Modified
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // <--- Modified
  ss.getRange(row,4).setValue("CONTACTED");
  console.log("Post function called");
  if (typeof e !== 'undefined')
  console.log(e.parameter);
  sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");  // <--- Added
}
```

#### Testing

When you test above Web Apps using a curl command, you can use the following curl command.

```
curl -L -d "key=value" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?row=5"
```

- `-d "key=value"` is used for requesting with the POST method to `doPost` as the dummy.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `row` is used as the request body like your script.

#### Modified script 2:

```
function doPost(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("16XSfRDLY1RdrUxHujbRCPX6eSh4CqP7ES2kVVDCGgoI");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("INGRESOSDEDINERO");
  var myObj=JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var row=myObj.row;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // <--- Modified
  ss.getRange(row,4).setValue("CONTACTED");
  console.log("Post function called");
  if (typeof e !== 'undefined')
  console.log(e.parameter);
  sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");  // <--- Added
}
```

#### Testing

When you test above Web Apps using a curl command, you can use the following curl command.

```
curl -L -d "{\"row\": 5}" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)